# Lambda Issue, or cross validation

Tags: r, glmnet

I am doing double cross validation with LASSO of `glmnet` package, however when I plot the results I am getting lambda of 0 - 150000 which is unrealistic in my case, not sure what is wrong I am doing, can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

```
calcium = read.csv("calciumgood.csv", header=TRUE)
dim(calcium)
n = dim(calcium)[1]
calcium = na.omit(calcium)
names(calcium)

library(glmnet)  # use LASSO model from package glmnet 
lambdalist = exp((-1200:1200)/100)  # defines models to consider


fulldata.in = calcium
x.in = model.matrix(CAMMOL~. - CAMLEVEL - AGE,data=fulldata.in)
y.in = fulldata.in[,2]
k.in = 10 
n.in = dim(fulldata.in)[1]
groups.in = c(rep(1:k.in,floor(n.in/k.in)),1:(n.in%%k.in))  
set.seed(8)
cvgroups.in = sample(groups.in,n.in)  #orders randomly, with seed (8) 
#LASSO cross-validation
cvLASSOglm.in = cv.glmnet(x.in, y.in, lambda=lambdalist, alpha = 1, nfolds=k.in, foldid=cvgroups.in)
plot(cvLASSOglm.in$lambda,cvLASSOglm.in$cvm,type="l",lwd=2,col="red",xlab="lambda",ylab="CV(10)")
whichlowestcvLASSO.in = order(cvLASSOglm.in$cvm)[1];     min(cvLASSOglm.in$cvm)
bestlambdaLASSO = (cvLASSOglm.in$lambda)[whichlowestcvLASSO.in];     bestlambdaLASSO
abline(v=bestlambdaLASSO)
bestlambdaLASSO  # this is the lambda for the best LASSO model
LASSOfit.in = glmnet(x.in, y.in, alpha = 1,lambda=lambdalist)  # fit the model across possible lambda
LASSObestcoef = coef(LASSOfit.in, s = bestlambdaLASSO); LASSObestcoef # coefficients for the best model fit
```

[image]

Comment: Could you advise where to get calciumgood.csv?

Answer (score 0):

I found the dataset you referring at
[Calcium, inorganic phosphorus and alkaline phosphatase levels in elderly patients](http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/calciumgood.dat.txt).

Basically the data are "dirty", and it is a possible reason why the algorithm does not converge properly. E.g. there are `771` year old patients, bisides `1` and `2` for male and female, there is `22` for sex encodeing etc.

As for your case you removed only `NA`s.

You need to check `data.frame` imported types as well. E.g. instead of factors it could be imported as integers (SEX, Lab and Age group) which will affect the model.

I think you need:
1) cleanse the data;
2) if doesnot work submit *.csv file